# NetBeans - have to clean build every time i have to debug

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-7

I got three PCs running Netbeans.

on two this problem doesn't arrive. i.e. change code and hit debug button, the changed code is affected in debug.

Whereas in the third PC i have to rebuild the whole project (takes about 1 min 30 secs) to see changed code in debug applied. What am i doing wrong? How to resolve this issue?

Compile on Save is on on all related projects.

NetBeans 7.1.1

Comment: Do you have "compile on save" checked in the project properties?

Comment: yes. All projects ... if i disable them then it might make sense that i have to build every time

Comment: Have you tried deleting the cache lately? `C:\Users\{user}\.netbeans\7.1.1\var\cache` under Windows 7??

Comment: will try that in a moment ...

Comment: @MadProgrammer that did the trick ... can you please put that in an answer so that i many accept it

Comment: Glad it work, as request now an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting the cache `C:\Users\{user}\.netbeans\7.1.1\var\cache` under Windows 7

Comment: in case of Windows XP C:\Documents and Settings\{user}

Comment: @madprogrammer how about for fedora linux

Comment: Not familiar with linux, but I'd imagine it would be something like `~/.netbeans/...`

Comment: I'm having the same problem with Netbeans 8.0.2 on Windows 7 and I can't find any such path. The closest thing to it is `C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\nb\var\cache`

Comment: `c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache` or `c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.1\var` under Windows 7?

Comment: @QA_Col I'd start with `c:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache`

Comment: Found it in C:\Users\{USER}\.nbi\product-cache

Comment: @Bob Yep, that was 4 years ago :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer It seems like problems never get old :P